# Trying to install spotify with libssl1.0.0

Tags: debian, openssl

I would like to install spotify client but it's complaining that it can't find the old libssl0.9.8 So I created a symlink to libssl1.0.0:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so**.1.0.0** /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

This did not work. So I made another one:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so**.1.0.0** /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

Also failed to install the spotify client. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you on? And how are you trying to install Spotify? (package, repository, etc.)

Comment: debian wheezy. i am trying to install spotify from its repo (http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 are binary incompatible. The Spotify client you have is built against 0.9.8 and will not run, even if you get the link right. Get yourself a package of Spotify fit for your version of the distribution you're using.

In case Spotify does not build it for your combination of distribution/version, then you'll have to build OpenSSL 0.9.8 yourself. See [this thread about Debian Wheezey](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/libssl1-0-0-Debian-Wheezy-Ubuntu-Precise/td-p/42657) on the Spotify forums for more details.

Comment: thanks, that worked. do you think i will get package conflicts in the future (since i have both old and new versions of libssl)?

Comment: Depends on how you installed it. Did you install a forward ported package, installed the Squeeze package, or manually compiled/installed?

Comment: I've installed this one using gdebi: http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20110406T213352Z/pool/main/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

There are a few symbolic links you probably have to create. For OpenSSL, at least `libcrypto` on top of `libssl`.

For Fedora (adapt to your distro at will):

```
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so libnspr4.so.0d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libnss3.so libnss3.so.1d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so libnssutil3.so.1d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libplc4.so libplc4.so.0d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libplds4.so libplds4.so.0d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so libsmime3.so.1d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libssl3.so libssl3.so.1d
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0j libssl.so.0.9.8
ln -sf /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0j libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Could you provide the exact command and error?

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/ptsephLN